# Unable to download SQL Server on M1 Mac

Tags: sql-server, docker

I have been trying to download SQL Server on my Mac with an Apple Chip. I've been following the steps that include downloading docker and entering code into my terminal to set up the images and containers within docker. However, when I try and type in this code:

```
docker run --name SQLServer -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=12345OHdf%e' -e 'MSSQL_PID=Express’ -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

I get the following response in terminal:

> WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match
> the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform
> was requested
> a1c6173553fc3ae53d28cc4c8bef452fdd322bf1ab2074124803c2275a97e587

I was wondering if anybody would be able to help me in fixing this problem

Comment: You can't use that image on an M1. You'll need to use the Edge flavor. I wrote about this [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7099/testing-sql-server-edge-and-docker-on-the-latest-macbooks/?utm_source=AaronBertrand).

Comment: Thank you so much for that! However I do have a question on one of the steps in your article. When it talks about Azure SQL and all of the steps to input into the terminal, I attempted to copy and paste it and run it but it did not work

Comment: What did you copy and paste _exactly_, and what does "did not work" mean?

Answer (score 6):

Using the azure sql edge docker image and installing mssql tool separately worked for us.

This is the Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge:latest

EXPOSE 1433

COPY ./database/schema.sql /database/schema.sql

ENV SA_PASSWORD "MyP@w0rd"
ENV SQLCMDPASSWORD "MyP@w0rd"
ENV ACCEPT_EULA "Y"

RUN (mkdir -p /opt/mssql-tools/bin && cd /opt/mssql-tools/bin && wget https://github.com/microsoft/go-sqlcmd/releases/download/v0.8.0/sqlcmd-v0.8.0-linux-arm64.tar.bz2 \
    && bzip2 -d sqlcmd-v0.8.0-linux-arm64.tar.bz2 && tar -xvf sqlcmd-v0.8.0-linux-arm64.tar && chmod 755 sqlcmd)

RUN  /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr & sleep 20 && \
     /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -d master \
     -Q "create database testdb;" && \
     /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -d master -i  /database/schema.sql


CMD /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
```

Comment: What command did you use to build and run the Dockerfile?

Comment: Used docker-compose for this one `docker-compose build test-database` and  `docker-compose up test-database` in that case

Answer (score 0):

From the docker docs:

> "Not all images are available for ARM64 architecture. You can add
> --platform linux/amd64 to run an Intel image under emulation. In particular, the mysql image is not available for ARM64. You can work
> around this issue by using a mariadb image."

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but here's a workaround for this using an open source tool called Lima and Rosetta as the VM: https://dev.to/srburnham/forget-azure-sql-edge-on-a-m1-mac-run-full-blown-sql-server-linux-instead-a-how-to-6d2. Saves you from having to resort to the cutdown edge version.

Answer (score -1):

I have followed the tutorial on the website but I can't connect azure data studio to the SQL Server instance ... while he is running
@Aaron Bertrand

I finally use Azure Sql Database instead of SSMS

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).